# Convert one object to another in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am using Angular 7 and I am getting all details into `const fieldErrors = error.error.fieldErrors;`

```
0:
code: "Size"
field: "studentName"
message: "Length of characters should be between 1 to 255"
resource: "studentDto"
__proto__: Object
1:
code: "NotBlank"
field: "studentName"
message: "Program Name is mandatory"
resource: "studentDto"
__proto__: Object
2:
code: "NotBlank"
field: "studentDesc"
message: "Student Description is mandatory"
resource: "studentDto"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
```

I want to convert it into the

```
ServerResponse = {
   "studentName" {
        "Program Name is mandatory"
    },
    studentDesc {
       "Student Description is mandatory"
   }
}
```

Comment: what you want to get is not a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might probably want to convert it into a json with each field being an array, like below:

```
ServerResponse = {
    studentName: [
        "Length of characters should be between 1 to 255",
        "Program Name is mandatory"
    ],
    studentDesc: [
        "Student Description is mandatory"
    ]
}
```

In this way, multiple error messages for the same field can be fit into the same key.

You can loop through the `fieldErrors` array and manually assign the values.

```
let ServerResponse = {};
fieldErrors.forEach(fieldError => {
    if (ServerResponse[fieldError.field]) {
        ServerResponse[fieldError.field].push(fieldError.message);
    } else {
        ServerResponse[fieldError.field] = fieldError.message;
    }
});
```

If the field is already present in `ServerResponse`, you are adding the message to the list. If the field is not present, make a new entry.

Comment: Thanks, now how can we check 
`<div *ngIf="serverResponse.lengh" class="dxp-error dxp-required">
                {{serverResponse.studentName}}
  </div>
`

Comment: Since each field is an array, you will have to loop through them in HTML

`<div *ngIf="serverResponse.length && serverResponse.studentName" class="dxp-error dxp-required"> <p *ngFor="let message of serverResponse.studentName">{{message}}</p> </div>`

Comment: `serverResponse.length` > 0 like this ? Will you condition handle if its empty as well ?

Comment: For empty arrays, since the length is zero it will not pass `serverResponse.length` check. It is same as `serverResponse.length > 0`

Comment: Yeah I used that I am getting : Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Student Name is mandatory' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
`<input type="text" id="" class="input-box" aria-required="true" minlength="0" maxlength="255"
                    autocomplete="off" width="0" min="3" max="100" step="" [(ngModel)]="student.studentName"
                    name="studentName" required #studentName="ngModel" #inputRef="ngModel"`

Comment: How does your `serverResponse` look like? Did you modify it to the format in my answer or the one in your question?
The error says that `serverResponse.studentName` is not an array, which should be if following the format in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199948/discussion-between-paa-and-johns-mathew).

Comment: `{programDesc: "StuydentDescription is mandatory", studentName: "StudentName is mandatory"}`
This is working

`<div *ngIf="serverResponse.length" class="dxp-error dxp-required">
{{serverResponse.studentName}}
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the fieldErrors array and assign each field and message to ServerResponse object.

Try the below code:

```
let ServerResponse:any = {};
fieldErrors.forEach(item => {
    ServerResponse[item.field] = item.message;
});
```

Comment: you will need to specify `ServerResponse` type to any `let ServerResponse: any = {}` so that it allows you to insert keys in it

Answer (score 0):

```
ServerResponse = errors.reduce((result, cur) => (result[cur.field] = cur.message, result), {});
```

However you will lose items with same field property